# javascript array for loop i+1 returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, element, loops

array ref.length = 7 (0 - 6), and I want to try to match ref[0]['x'] to ref[1]['x'] I am doing this:

```
   for(var i=0;i<ref.length;i++){
      if( ref[i]['x'] != ref[i+1]['x'] && ref[i+1]['x'].length > 0 )
         //do something
   }
```

The for loop is iterating all the way to array number 6 then element 6+1 is blank so I get an error on the if statement line saying ref[i+1] is undefined....

is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i<ref.length-1; i++) { // Note the "-1".
```

This way when you use the index `i+1` you're still in bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Better:

```
for (var i=ref.length-2;i>=0;i--)
```

Javascript will evaluate the condition on each iteration, so it's generally preferable go backwards instead. With this construct "ref.length" is only evaluated once. Another alternative I like which will perform the same:

```
var i=ref.length-1;
while (i--) {

}
```

(Normally you'd be `i=ref.length-1` in the first example, and `i=ref.length` in the second, but you're trying to stay one less than the array length).

Answer (score 1):

`for (var i = 0; i < ref.length - 1; i++`)

Comment: Am I the only one who likes foreplay and maybe a bit of conversation before and after the act?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
for(var i=0;i<ref.length-1;i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just use ref.length-1 won't that solve your problem? I might not fully understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution.
Just count the counter again.

```
if( ref[i]['x'] != ref[++i]['x'] && ref[++i]['x'].length > 0 )
```